# node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(20,1): error TS1084: Invalid 'reference' directive syntax

Tags: node.js, typescript, compilation, tsconfig

I have a problem with typescript compilation. Has anybody else received this error?

> node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(20,1): error TS1084: Invalid
> 'reference' directive syntax.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./app",
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "listFiles": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./app/**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

typescript version in package.json: `"typescript": "^2.6.1"`

Answer (score 52):

Had the same issue. Open the file ../node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts

and remove the third slash

```
// <reference lib="es2015" />
```

compile again

Comment: But next time you clear node_modules and reinstall, or install on another machine, this is gone and you'll need to remember to do this again...

Comment: You can remove third slash but as it is less advisable to change the content of any node_modules folder, better update the typescript version to latest one.

Comment: I had problems with my testing, after hours of searching, this works like a charm =)

Comment: downgrading to "@types/node": "^7.0.7" looks like more wise solution

Comment: Before:  /// <reference lib="es2015" />
After:    // <reference lib="es2015" />

Comment: don't offer fake solutions. editing bundle files is never a good solution. it will be override at the first deployment or npm i

Answer (score 38):

I got the same error. I used the pinned version "@types/node": "7.0.7" in my package.json and got it working.

Comment: I updated my package.json with "@types/node": "7.0.7" and then ran the following: npm install --save @types/node. After that I was able to run npm start successfully. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

I have faced the same problem and found the solution is to update typescript to the latest version from the current version.

Make changes in the package.json file like below:

```
"devDependencies": {
     "typescript": "^3.9.7"
 }
```

Now "npm install typescript" , it will upgrade to latest version. Then run "ng serve" and it will compile successfully.

Answer (score 10):

**update TypeScript**

```
npm install typescript@latest --save-dev
```

Comment: it works, basically needs to update tS

Comment: It is the most suitable answer. It works for me as well.

Answer (score 8):

Its worked for me
ckeckout your tags for versions of TypeScript.
run `npm dist-tag ls @types/node` and look for your currently typescript version.

Then install the @types/node version supporting for typescript
[in my case I had to install 14.0.1 version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQkby.png)

reference: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/47250#issuecomment-687701880

Answer (score 3):

Had the same error and the fix was to use the previous version, check the version that you have in package.json for @types/node and see if you have the latest or not.
You can check here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node as it seams that there was a new update.

Comment: Gave you the vote up since you beat the answer above by more than a half hour, and it is better practice to update to the latest version (assuming the issue is fixed) than it is to just build to a specific version. Also, I do not understand why all of the answers recommending to update typescript are getting upvoted when the issue is obviously with `@types/node`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to change typescript version to '>=2.7.3'.
I think the version might depend on other packages.
probably need to try a couple of times to get the right version.
And don't forget to run install.

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading the `@type/node`.

I had the same issue  with

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "12.20.42",
}
```

I downgraded it to lower version and it compiles successfully

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "12.19.12",
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I have faced the same problem and found the solution is to update typescript to the latest version from the current version.

Make changes in the package.json file like below:

```
"devDependencies": {
     "typescript": "^3.9.7"
 }
```

Now `npm install typescript`, it will upgrade to the latest version. Then run "ng serve" and it will compile successfully.